# Can we implement the mint or burn function in the Safemoon protocol contract?

Tags: solidity, safemoon

I have forked the Safemoon contract and I want to implement the mint or burn function and safe moon contract using the IERC20 interface so it's not providing the functionality of the mint or burn function. And I little bit confused about how to implement them. Can you help me to implement both functions?

Answer (score 0):

Create new contract IERC20.sol, first copy paste all IERC20.sol funtionality in, then copy paste mint and burn funtions in this contract and inherit from it. For example recently i did this with mint funtion, and this is how i implemented it in new IERC20:

```
function mint(address to, uint amount) external;
```